Was Benjamin Franklin denounced for inventing the lightning rod?
This article and other which have cited it make the claim that upon inventing the lightning rod that Benjamin Franklin was denounced  by parties unspecified in the sources.

While most people hailed the lightning rod as a lifesaver, some religious leaders objected that Franklin was attempting to interfere with one of God’s most effective methods of punishing sinners, to which he replied, "Surely the thunder of Heaven is no more supernatural than the rain, hail, or sunshine of Heaven, against the inconvenience of which we guard by roofs and shades without scruple."

One source attributes this to Ken Burns' documentary on Franklin, which I don't have access to. If someone can simply find a decent source for this claim, who made it, and what it was, that will satisfy my curiosity. This sounds to my cynical ears like a story that was too good to check.

Highly related: Was there any theological opposition to the lightning rod? and Was the 1755 Cape Ann earthquake widely ascribed to Benjamin Franklin’s lightning rod?

Welcome to Skeptics! "One source attributes this" - please cite the source so we can see this for ourselves.

Fun fact: around the same time Franklin invented the lighting rod, man called Prokop Diviš in Kingdom of Bohemia independently also invented it. His invention was actually torn down by an angry mob during a drought, because of fears it breaks clouds and prevents rain. There was no religious element to this though, and I have to concede that while the farmers were wrong, given the state of knowledge at that time, their concerns were somewhat understandable or even reasonable. The lighting rod was reelected a year later.

@TomášZato "The lighting rod was reelected a year later." I assume you mean 're-erected' here but the idea of a lightning rod being elected to office is somewhat amusing.

A source might come from "Amish Society" of John A. Hostetler, that refers to the discussions of the General Conference of Ministers, which began in 1862. From this other source : Levi Miller of Holmes County, Ohio, in the initial session of 1862, listed among other threatening innovations that were objectionable to many : lightning rods, lotteries, likenesses (photographs), insurance, and big meetinghouses.

In Franklin's 12 April 1753 letter to Cadwallader Colden, Franklin wrote:

Kanster opposes your Principles, and Nollet mine. He has lately wrote and published 6 Long Letters, directed to me, on the Subjects of my Pamphlet, in which he imagines he has taken me all to pieces. I have read and consider’d them, and remain of the same Sentiments. In one or two Places, he seems to apply to the superstitious Prejudices of the Populace, which I think unworthy of a Philosopher: He speaks as if he thought it Presumption in Man, to propose guarding himself against the Thunders of Heaven! Surely the Thunder of Heaven is no more supernatural than the Rain, Hail or Sunshine of Heaven, against the Inconveniencies of which we guard by Roofs and Shades without Scruple.

"Kanster" is Abraham Gotthelf Kästner.
"Nollet" is Jean-Antoine Nollet.
See Jean-Antoine Nollet: Letters on Electricity
and Lettres sur l'électricité
Those are the sources related to the OP quote; however, there is no indication that Nollet's objections were actually religious or superstitious.
Nonetheless, there were people who had religious objections as the diary of John Adams (1758) says:

Dr. Arbuthnot ...The other night I happened to be at the Doctor’s with Ben Veasey; he began to prate upon the presumption of philosophy in erecting iron rods to draw the lightning from the clouds. His brains were in a ferment, and he railed and foamed against those points and the presumption that erected them, in language taken partly from Scripture and partly from the disputes of tavern philosophy, in as wild, mad a manner as King Lear raves against his daughter’s disobedience and ingratitude, and against the meanness of the storm in joining with his daughters against him, in Shakspeare’s Lear. He talked of presuming upon God, as Peter attempted to walk upon the water; attempting to control the artillery of heaven—an execution that mortal man can’t stay—the elements of heaven; fire, heat, rain, wind, &c.


The context on the linked pages has me thinking that Nollet was simply being grandiose in his rebuke, and Franklin is further muddying the situation via "[Nollet] speaks as if...". From the page on Nollet's criticisms, Can Franklin really believe that lightning is now in men’s control? What evidence is there that a lightning-charged cloud large enough to cover a city, will be emptied in a few minutes by means of a rod or metal wire no larger than a finger? Anyone who would credit such an idea would propose preventing floods by inserting small tubes into the banks of streams.

In other words, I don't believe Nollet truly denounces Franklin on theological grounds. This related thread has me thinking there probably were such people out there, though.

This covers Franklins rebuke, but the question was if he was denounced for intervening with Gods way to punish sinners.  That core part of the claim is not addressed here.

The linked post about Nollet's Letters on Electricity suggests Franklin himself charged Nollet with this denunciation of his (Franklin's) own invention.

@FrançoisJurain The letters are about 300 pages total, in French. https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1041479b.image Since you know French, you could see from there if there was any religious or superstitious basis to Nollet's criticism.

Looks like he reasserts his position in a purely scientific controversy. It would be extremely weird if Nollet, a European luminary in the experimental study of electricity, called religious arguments in defense of his scientific theory. His résumé on en.WP follows closely the one on fr.WP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Antoine_Nollet. I'll have a look at the Letters to B. F. & comment again if I find an unscientific argument in them.

So.! 1. "denounced as attempting to interfere with God's [way] of punishing sinners", definitely not in Nollet's Lettres and, I'll wager, in no other work of his, either. 2. Franklin's depiction of his opponent, as quoted in the answer, is completely alien to the actual contents of the Lettres and borders on the libellous. From them, I would describe Nollet as the quintessential Skeptics.SE poster.

The 1st letter, if any, is s/what unscientific in its tone. It is addressed to a pupil of his and  Nollet obviously plays chevalier servant to her. He specially cautions her that the Marly-la-Ville experiments are miles away from proving the infaillible device against lightning which Franklin's followers advertise.

He is also quite condescending about Franklin's editors in London, the French translation of his pamphlet, the enthusiasm of the gazettes about the Marly-la-Ville experiments, their subsequent marketing and the public craze that followed. Also, he lays it condescendingly on the backwardness of the New World Colonies that Franklin did not acknowledge previous European publications similar to his own, which I surmise is a manipulative way to imply plagiarism and, possibly, is what incensed Franklin against him.

So, in summary (and please disagree with me if you do) it's not so much that the objections were on theological grounds as much as that theological premises were tied up in the scale of the perceived problem, and definitely in the rhetoric. Which gives a "No" as the answer to my original question, which was whether we was denounced on theological grounds.

@ChrisB.Behrens Depends: he may have been, definitely not by Nollet. It looks like the quote in your question is indeed from Franklin and that he actually directed at Nollet on the occasion of his Lettres, as explained in the accepted answer. My read of them is, Franklin charged him in bad faith with echoing the theological objections of the obscurantist party. Nollet was not a religious locomotive in his time, so this says nothing of what they preached about the lightning rod, and even less what they thought of it.
